# Validating RSS 2.0 with atom:link in channel element

Tags: xml, validation, rss, atom-feed

I can see several questions and answers relating to valid RSS 2.0, but I'm not seeing an answer to my problem, sorry if this has been covered before.

I'm trying to validate XML downloaded from user supplied URLs to see if they are in fact RSS 2.0 files or not. To do this I'm using XmlReader and other stuff from dotNet.

I'm having problems sourcing all of the schemas required to fully validate a standard Wordpress feed, but I do have an RSS 2.0 XSD from codeplex, and an atom XSD from elsewhere, I also have an XML XSD for some basics.

When I validate the feed, it validates successfully, but I have a warning because atom:link is not found in the schema.

I can see in the schema for atom that a proper atom file would only have either <feed> or <entry> root elements. If I add an appropriate link root element this validates.

My question is, what schemas and settings do I need to get my RSS Validator to allow/recognise/validate atom:link within rss/channel?

For RSS, I'm using the schema at http://rss2schema.codeplex.com/

For Atom, I'm using the schema at http://www.kbcafe.com/rss/atom.xsd.xml

My Validation Test code looks like this:

```
string xml="";

try
{
    //Download the RSS File
    //To Do: Verify against RSS schema
    //var Client = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.ia.uk.com/feed");
    var Client = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("C:\\Development\\euspen2013\\Website\\RabjohnMark-branch\\App_Data\\test.xml");
    var r = Client.GetResponse();
    var rs = r.GetResponseStream();
    var valerrors = new List<string>();
    var valwarnings = new List<string>();

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

    settings.Schemas.Add(null, "C:\\Development\\euspen2013\\Website\\RabjohnMark-branch\\App_Data\\rss-2_0.xsd");
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, "C:\\Development\\euspen2013\\Website\\RabjohnMark-branch\\App_Data\\dc-simple.xsd");
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, "C:\\Development\\euspen2013\\Website\\RabjohnMark-branch\\App_Data\\xml.xsd");
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, "C:\\Development\\euspen2013\\Website\\RabjohnMark-branch\\App_Data\\atom.xsd");

    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;

    settings.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler((s, a) => { if (a.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error) valerrors.Add(a.Message); else valwarnings.Add(a.Message); });

    var rr = XmlReader.Create(rs, settings);

    var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(rr.NameTable);

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(rr);

    rr.Close();
    rs.Close();

    if (valerrors.Count() > 0) return; else xml = doc.OuterXml;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return;
}
```

I hope someone can help to add some clarity to any aspect of this.

Thanks,

Mark